# How to Write Image File from Request Body Without Writing to Memory Nodejs

Tags: java, android, node.js, image, express

I'm trying to `(HTTP) POST` an image to a Nodejs server that is configured using Express. I have been able to accomplish this successfully using JSON, but unless I am mistaken, there is no way to obtain the image string without loading the entire request body into a new variable before parsing it as JSON. Since images are quite large and the image should already be stored in the request body anyway, is there a way to immediately pipe the image contents into `fs.writeFile()`? The content type for the request does not have to be JSON. I have tried using a querystring as well, but that was unsuccessful. The content type cannot be just an image though because I have to include a tag for the image too (in this case the user's email address).

Here is the code for when I attempted to use a query string. It is located in a post route method for the express app:

```
fs.writeFile('profiles/images/user.png', new Buffer(req.body.image, 'base64'), 
    function(error) 
    {           
        if (error)
            res.end(error);
    }
);
```

No error occurs, and the code creates the .png file, but the file is somehow corrupted and is larger than it should be.

All of this is actually for an Android app, so here is also the Java code that I am using to send the request:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(UPLOAD_PICTURE_URL).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

String image = Base64.encodeToString(
                   IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(filePath)), 
                   Base64.NO_WRAP
               );

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("email=" + email + "&image=" + image);
out.close();
```

Perhaps this belongs in another topic, but along the same lines, does anybody know a way to pipe the file input stream in the android code directly to the `URLConnection`'s output stream with base64 encoding? I have tried writing the string literal (the `out.write()` line above ^) and then creating a `Base64OutputStream` to write the image before piping that stream into the `URLConnection`'s outputstream, but calling `req.body.image` in the node app after doing that just returns undefined. And finally, does anybody know if `IOUtils.toByteArray()` (from Apache Commons), when used as the input argument for an input/output stream constructor, writes the entire byte array to memory anyway on the Android side? If so, is there a way of avoiding that too?

Thanks in advance.